Mail command line
I am using a application called Mail but i can't send to my own email-adresses?
But i can't send any emails what is wrong?
mail -s "Test Email" tm@kth.se

Cc: 
Testing
 
jonathan@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573:~$ mail
"/var/mail/jonathan": 2 messages 1 new 1 unread
 U   1 Mail Delivery Syst Mon Apr  8 09:26  91/3656  Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
>N   2 Mail Delivery Syst Mon Apr  8 10:04  75/2600  Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
? 
Return-Path: <>
X-Original-To: jonathan@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573
Delivered-To: jonathan@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573
Received: by jonathan-Aspire-E5-573 (Postfix)
    id 9D0AF565866; Mon,  8 Apr 2024 10:04:59 +0200 (CEST)
Date: Mon,  8 Apr 2024 10:04:59 +0200 (CEST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573 (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: jonathan@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="34D4E56585B.1712563499/jonathan-Aspire-E5-573"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-Id: <20240408080459.9D0AF565866@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--34D4E56585B.1712563499/jonathan-Aspire-E5-573
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is the mail system at host jonathan-aspire-e5-573.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<tm@kth.se>: host mailfilter-ng-4.sunet.se[89.45.235.5] said: 550 5.7.1 Sender
    domain does not exists (b17d6644-f57e-11ee-8900-45cb70cd6bd9) (in reply to
    end of DATA command)
--More--


You need to add some more detailed information. Which mail transfer agent are you using? Did you install the mailutils package? If you're using postfix, is it properly configured?

@ArturMeinild i used these instructions from this site https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/send-email-linux-command-line ? I think i used mailutils

Ok. I'm not sure how postfix auto-configured itself when you choose "Internet Site", but I remember configuring a whole lot more when I installed postfix some years ago. It's possible that the receiving mailserver kth.se simply denies any emails that are not signed and DNS validated (DMARC/DKIM), so you might have to look into this. Email on the internet is not an easy topic...

The receiving SMTP at sunet.se tells you exactly why it rejects the message:
550 5.7.1 Sender domain does not exists.

Forgiving it its grammar mistake, it still has a point. Assuming that your sender address was jonathan@jonathan-Aspire-E5-573 (as this is where your MTA is bouncing to), then you are sending from domain jonathan-Aspire-E5-573, which is not currently a TLD in DNS.
Whether this is sufficient ground for rejecting the relay is up to postmaster@sunet.se.

Thanks for the clarification. Maybe you could add that this (implicitly) means you have to configure postfix with a proper domain registered in DNS to send external mail.

@ArturMeinild I would have added that information if it were the solution to the problem, but (as you also pointed out) without more context it's hard to figure out what the issue is. "I think I used mailutils" is little to go on.
